# Category attributes on frontend

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have a `multiselect` attribute in my categories named `location`

How do I display the selected / saved values on the frontend?

Thanks

Comment: $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_category', 'location');
foreach ( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option){
$attributeArray[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
}

print_r($attributeArray);

Comment: use to get all option available for location (not selected/save) may this help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add the attribute to the colleciton via event:
"catalog_category_flat_loadnodes_before"

```
$observer->getSelect()->columns(
    array( 'location' )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$category->getResource()
            ->getAttribute('location')
                ->getSource()
                    ->getOptionText($category->getData('location'))
```

Comment: I'm trying to use `$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()` to use as the $category object. Using your code returns `bool(false)` when I var_dump the result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

register an ovserver in magento via xml:

```
<events>
     <catalog_category_flat_loadnodes_before>
            <observers>
                <category_add_attribute>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>myModule/observer_catalog_category</class>
                    <method>addMenuAttributes</method>
                </category_add_attribute>
            </observers>
     </catalog_category_flat_loadnodes_before>
</events>
```

and then in your Class

```
    class MyModule_Namespace_Model_Observer_Catalog_Category
    {

        public function addMenuAttributes( Varien_Event_Observer $observer )
        {
            $observer->getSelect()->columns(
                    array( 'custom_attribute_name' )
            );
        }

    }
```

add the customAttribute